# Change Wordpress Uploads Folder To Root

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, directory

I have my Wordpress installed on (for ex.) mysite.com/core/

And I need to change the uploads folder to host all the files on my upper folder, meaning mysite.com/.

I've already tried to add to the wp-config.php file, the following:
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'' ); (didn't work) ..... define( 'UPLOADS', '/..'.'' ); (didn't work) ..... define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'/..' ); (didn't work) ..... define( 'UPLOADS', '../'.'' ); (didn't work) ..... define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'../' ); (didn't work)

Even with the "**DIR**" did not work.

All I get it's all sort of wrong urls, with multiple slashes (/), and not going upper than my "core" folder...

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder:

> It is always relative to ABSPATH, therefore does not require a leading
>   slash.

In testing on my local install, this works:

```
define('UPLOADS','');
```

Comment: You're correct, that works IF I wish to "upload" media to "main wordpress folder". But I want to go 1 folder back.

My Wordpress is at mysite.com/core/
I wish to upload media to mysite.com

So I can get clean media URLs, without showing my "core" folder where Wordpress is at.

Comment: The second half of this link https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-upload-dir/, says one could store the uploads in a subdomain. If so, should be able to do top level directory.  Suggest grab the plugin mentioned and see what the code does.